How can I rename a column in a list of data frames and the name of the column depends on the position of the data frame?
I have a list of three data frames (df1, df2, and df3) each with three columns (x, y, and z). I would like to rename a column (z) for all data frames, but the new name of the column depends on the specific data frame, or its position in the list.
For example, my data look like this:
df1<- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                 y=c(10:20),
                 z=c(20:30))
df2<- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                 y=c(10:20),
                 z=c(20:30))
df3<- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                 y=c(10:20),
                 z=c(20:30))
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3) 

and I would like the output to look like this:
df1:
| x  | y  | A  |
| -- | -- | -- |
| 0  | 10 | 20 | 
| 1  | 11 | 21 |

df2:
| x  | y  | B  |
| -- | -- | -- |
| 0  | 10 | 20 | 
| 1  | 11 | 21 |

df3:
| x  | y  | C  |
| -- | -- | -- |
| 0  | 10 | 20 | 
| 1  | 11 | 21 |

I do not want to use a for loop, so I have been attempting to work with lapply() or purrr::map(), but I am not sure I fully understand the structure. Here is code that I have attempted, but it renames all column Z to A
columns <- c(A, B, C)
lapply(lst, function(df, name) {
names(df)[3] <- name
 return(df)}, columns)


If you run lapply over a range of integers 1:length(lst) then you can use this to get the required data frame and the nth letter for the rename.
lapply(1:length(lst), \(x) {result <- lst[[x]]; names(result)[3] <- LETTERS[x]; return(result)})


One option could be to use map2() and use non-standard evaluation (chapters 19 and 20 of advanced R) to rename the columns, e.g.
library(tidyverse)

df1<- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                 y=c(10:20),
                 z=c(20:30))
df2<- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                 y=c(10:20),
                 z=c(20:30))
df3<- data.frame(x=c(0:10),
                 y=c(10:20),
                 z=c(20:30))
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3) 

map2(c("A", "B", "C"), lst, \(.x, lst) rename(lst, !!.x := "z"))
#> [[1]]
#>     x  y  A
#> 1   0 10 20
#> 2   1 11 21
#> 3   2 12 22
#> 4   3 13 23
#> 5   4 14 24
#> 6   5 15 25
#> 7   6 16 26
#> 8   7 17 27
#> 9   8 18 28
#> 10  9 19 29
#> 11 10 20 30
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     x  y  B
#> 1   0 10 20
#> 2   1 11 21
#> 3   2 12 22
#> 4   3 13 23
#> 5   4 14 24
#> 6   5 15 25
#> 7   6 16 26
#> 8   7 17 27
#> 9   8 18 28
#> 10  9 19 29
#> 11 10 20 30
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>     x  y  C
#> 1   0 10 20
#> 2   1 11 21
#> 3   2 12 22
#> 4   3 13 23
#> 5   4 14 24
#> 6   5 15 25
#> 7   6 16 26
#> 8   7 17 27
#> 9   8 18 28
#> 10  9 19 29
#> 11 10 20 30

Created on 2024-07-12 with reprex v2.1.0

Great, thank you, this worked for me! I think I found an alternative solution with map2

Glad you solved your problem @Clarkie :)

Adapted from [this][1] post
 rename_function = function(.x, .y) {
  names(.x)[names(.x) == 'dat'] = .y
  .x
  }

columns <- c(A, B, C)

map2(.x = lst,
     .y = columns,
     ~rename_function(.x, .y)
     )


You forgot the hyperlink :)

Try
lapply(seq(lst), \(i) setNames(lst[[i]], c("x", "y", LETTERS[i])))

